# Error when refreshing query

Tags: vba, excel

I'm recording a macro to automate the process of gathering P/E ratio information from a website for various stock tickers. The macro involves two web queries. I recorded them both the exact same way, and they both use the same URL. One of these queries works fine, and the other gives an

> error 1004 "Application-defined or object-defined error"

I have pasted the code for that query below.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="MSFT PE Ratio (TTM) Range, Past 5 Years", _
        Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    
    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents(""https://ycharts.com/companies/" & ActiveCell.Value & "/pe_ratio""))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Data3 = Source{3}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data3,{{""Column1"", type text}, {""Column2"", type number}, {""Column3"", type date}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.Name = "query2"
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array( _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""" & ActiveCell.Value & "PE Ratio (TTM) Range, Past 5 Years"";Extended Properties=" _
        , """"""), Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array( _
        "SELECT * FROM [" & ActiveCell.Value & "PE Ratio (TTM) Range, Past 5 Years]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "_PE_Ratio__TTM__Range__Past_5_Years"
        **.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False** <-- this is where I get the error
    End With
```

Comment: before post anything, read how to post and format use for code.

Comment: Are you sure you're not getting that error on the line `.ListObject.DisplayName = "_PE_Ratio__TTM__Range__Past_5_Years"`? Because you'd get error 1004 if you reused the same name. Although you'd also get an error on the line `ActiveSheet.Name = "query2"` again because of the duplicate name. Also, can you post the other (working) query to compare?

Answer (score 0):

1. This is code for one web query and one database query. Not two webqueries.
2. Both querytypes can make use of parameters which you can attach to a cell and set to automatically refresh the querytable when that cell changes.

See: [Webquery with parameters](http://jkp-ads.com/Articles/WebQuery.asp) and http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/12/13/parameters-in-excel-external-data-queries/